# How to use SQL to analyze state duration in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

Data are as follows:

```sql
create table states(state STRING);
insert into states values
('2020-01-01 10:00:00', 'starting'),
('2020-01-01 10:30:00', 'running'),
('2020-01-03 16:00:00', 'error'),
('2020-01-03 18:30:00', 'starting'),
('2020-01-03 19:30:00', 'running'),
('2020-01-05 12:00:00', 'stopping');
```

How to get the duration of the running state?